# Determine the region at xy plane where $(1+3y^3)y´=x^2$ has unique solution at $(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i determine the region at xy plane where:

$$(1+3y^3)y´=x^2$$

has unique solution at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: Check the existence theorem for first order differential equation. A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296796/existence-and-uniqueness-theorem).

Comment: Yes, but how can i apply it??

Comment: See the link I added in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write the equation as $y' = \dfrac{x^2}{1+3y^3}$.  Where could there be problems with the right side?

Comment: There are problems at $y=-1$? are there more troubles?

Comment: what problems do you think there are at $y=-1$?